# TemplateRef Content to Variable

Tags: angular, typescript, transclusion

I would like to get the innerText of the `ng-content` of a component as a simple string to be able to reuse it.

I tried something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <div class="text-container">
      <span class="text" [title]="text">{{text}}</span>
    </div>
    <ng-template #text>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('text') text: TemplateRef<string>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.text);
  }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
<my-com>
  My simple string text
</my-com>
```

The goal is to get my string `My simple string text` into the variable `text` ...

Thoughts?

Comment: Does that text even show up with above example? You would need to stamp the template somewhere for the content to become real (being added to the DOM). I doubt this can work. I think you should require a template reference that contains `My simple string text` and stamp this template as often as you want. `<ng-content>` projection is only for showing existing content on a specific location, not for passing it around.

Comment: No the text isn't shown because I just have the TemplateRef in the variable text. This is my point, how can I take the innerText of my template. If I put a ng-container with a template outlet, it works but I need also to put my text in the title attribute

Comment: There is no `innerText` as long as there is no `<ng-content>` and as long as the `<ng-template>` isn't stamped there won't be a `<ng-content>`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution corresponding to what I wanted to do:

**[Stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-text-ellipsis)**

*app.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <text-ellipsis>My very very very very long text sentence</text-ellipsis>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    div {
      width:100px
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent  {
}
```

*text-ellipsis.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'text-ellipsis',
  template: `
    <div class="text-container">
      <span [title]="text.innerText" #text><ng-content></ng-content></span>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .text-container {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  `]
})
export class TextEllipsisComponent {
}
```

In this way, I can display the text provided by the `ng-content` AND set it in the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think what you want can be made work (see comments below your question)

My suggestion is

```ts
<ng-template #text>My simple string text</ng-template>
<my-comp [text]="text"></my-comp>
```

and get it like

```ts
  @Input() text: TemplateRef<string>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('text', this.text);
  }
```

Then you can use the template reference to output it

```ts
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="text"></ng-container>
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xennaj?file=app/my.component.ts)

Comment: But I would like to display "My simple string text" and not the template object "[object,object]". 
It is exactly the same as https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abvfxy?file=app/my.component.ts but in my example, you have the benefit of removing the input parameter. 

I think the easiest way is to pass the real string value as an input of my component: <my-comp [text]="My simple string text"></my-comp>

but I just wanted to know if it is possible to do it using transclusion...

Comment: Sorry, forgot that output part. I updated the example